# How do I copy sharepoint list entries to another list when certain conditions are fulfilled (Status = publish & Audience = all)

Tags: list, copy-item

We want to publish a FAQ list on a sharepoint site. We have another list that people work on, in which the question is logged, a person that should answer it is tagged and so on. I would like to copy the list entries to another list when the "Choice column for the audience" is set to "all" (which is done when the question is first logged) and the "Sign off person" sets the "Choice column for the status" to "publish". How can I do this?

I checked out Power Automate/Flow but I can't find anything that lets me put the conditions as described above.

Thank you very much for your help!
Franziska

Answer (score 2):

Try below steps using Power Automate ,

1. Create a automated flow When item is created and modified
2. Add condition action and check status value is equal to publish
3. if Yes then add new action Create item
4. Connect to another list and add dynamic content
   [image: Check Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Do I need to "get item" somewhere, too?

Comment: if you want copy list item when status value modified to publish then above screenshot will work(No need to use get items) / if you created scheduled flow then you need get items, scheduled flow run on hourly , daily ,monthly, etc. as per configuration